# How to split multiple columns into rows

Tags: mysql, split

How can I split columns "MyCode" and "MyAmount" into multiple rows in MySQL 8.0.33

I tried it with only 1 column, but with 2 columns I can't get it right

| MyID | MyCode | MyAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1209 | MR;CA,KK | 3.95;100.15;-9.75 |
| 1210 | CA;GU | 13.75;1004.60 |

The expected result:

| MyID | MyCode | MyAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1209 | MR | 3.95 |
| 1209 | CA | 100.15 |
| 1209 | KK | -9.75 |
| 1210 | CA | 13.75 |
| 1210 | GU | 1004.60 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could try what has been answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows).

Comment: i tried it with only 1 column, but with 2 or more columns i can't get it right

Comment: If you can't query your data, that may be a sign that you should store it in a different way. In this case, as rows of a second table, with one value in each column per row, not as semicolumn-separated strings of values. This is a one-to-many relationship.